# Identifying the functional dependency and schema

Tags: database

(1) Identify FDs (only direct , non-trivial and non-transitive ones)
(2) Find a primary key of the current table as it is.

Sales (StoreName, StoreOwner, Item_Name, Item_Model_number, Item_maker, Price) - A store name is unique. 
-   A store sells many items but a store has only one owner.
-   The same item with the same model number may be sold at different stores at different prices. 
-   Each item with a particular model number in a store has only one price. 
-   One item may be produced by many makers, but a specific model is produced by only one maker.

I have a sort of confusion solving this

Comment: So what's the confusion?

Comment: How to identify the functional dependencies from this?